# No change to website output after updating Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am attempting to get Rails to output "Hello World" by following the directions in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Starting off with an empty Rails project, I run the server and the local host page shows the Rails logo, as expected. The html address is http://, followed by a 3-digit number, a decimal, a 1-digit number, a decimal, the same 1-digit number, a decimal, a different 1-digit number, a colon and a 4-digit number. Next, I add or edit the following files and restart the server. However, there is no change in the local server page, even when I add "/articles" to the end of the html address on the local host page. (That said, the page doesn't crash, so I think I can rule out an error as opposed to a bug.)

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Reveal health status on /up that returns 200 if the app boots with no exceptions, otherwise 500.
  # Can be used by load balancers and uptime monitors to verify that the app is live.
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "posts#index"
  get "/articles", to: "articles#index"

end
```

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

app/views/articles/index.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `index.html.erb` not `index/html.erb`

Comment: That is a very peculiar description of a URL. The default `bin/rails s` address is simply `http://localhost:3000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` if you will.

Comment: @tadman Corrected. That was typo in my StackOverflow post, not my file name.

Comment: @tadman Yes, it was http://127.0.0.1:3000. I wasn't sure if that varied, by computer, so I didn't want to jeopardize my privacy.

Comment: What do you mean "there is no change", you've not shown any change in your post. Do you get that `Hello, Rails!` `h1` on your `/articles` page?

Comment: Fair enough. The convention is to express this as `x.x.x.x` or `a.b.c.d` where it's obvious those are placeholders, but rest assured, *everyone* lives at 127.0.0.1. Virtually all computers use that as the [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (localhost) address. This address has been the subject of many jokes, as giving that out to some amateur hacker will result in them attempting to hack their own computer.

Answer (score 1):

First, some basic context... the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`... here's a generalized breakdown on how these concepts work (please don't hit me with pedantic comments).

A basic URL is structured like this (see the [URL RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.1)):
`//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>`
You might not be familiar with some of these things because they're typically omitted from the kinds of URLs a normal internet user is typing or observing in their address bar. The URLs https://spaghetti:ramen@google.com:443 and http://spaghetti:ramen@google.com:80 will both take you to google.com in a web browser, but they're not the thing you're used to typing to get to Google Search. They work because the username and password arguments aren't needed to access the site, your DNS server is able to translate the host `google.com` to the IP of Google's remote host on the internet, 443 is the default networking port for https requests, and 80 is the default networking port for http requests.

When you type `google.com` into your modern browser, it should interpret that host argument and assume it needs to use the https protocol (rules describing how data is transmitted across a network). The https protocol uses the https service to securely connect to the website via port 443, which is the port registered for the https service in the [IANA Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=https).

When your browser sees `127.0.0.1` (or [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)), unless you've badly mucked with your hostfile it knows that the host is your local machine. The [default rails server port is 3000](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-server), so the address `http://127.0.0.1:3000` is telling your browser 'use the http protocol to take me to port 3000 on my local machine'.

### Your Actual Problem

Your rails server root is running at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`, but your routes file doesn't define any [routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) that would direct traffic hitting that address to a controller action. If `root 'posts#index'` were not commented out, it would direct traffic hitting the root to the `index` action inside your app's `PostsController`. Based on the routes file you've provided, you're going to need to go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/articles to hit `ArticlesController#index`; when you go to that address, you should see the request reflected in your terminal tab where you're running your rails server. If the address doesn't chain `:3000` after the host (before the path), your browser will probably default to trying to take you to a resource at port 80 (which is the wrong port for your server).

If you're going to that address and still not seeing anything, the server output in your terminal should be showing you a running log of the traffic your server is receiving and any errors (e.g., the controller action method you're routing to is not defined, the request is hitting your controller action but when it tries to render at the end it can't find the file where you've defined your view, etc.

Read the rails guides closely, they are really well-written and cover everything you need to know to go a long way with rails.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question. I have not learned the basics of networking, so I didn't understand most of the terminology you used, and the Rails documentation does not help me either. That's my problem, though, and I'll have to learn it.